# How to use .$$eval function

Tags: eval, puppeteer

I'm trying to run this code:

```js
var aaa = await page.$$eval(
  selector,
  list => (list, value) => {
    return resolve(list.find(element => element.textContent === value));
  },
  value
);
```

But I received an error.

Therefore, I tried to print the items in "list" (because I assumed that the problem is there), I tried this code:

```js
var aaa = await page.$$eval(selector, list => list);
```

And I received that "aaa" is empty.

Any idea what may be the problem?

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: In addition to the error you received, you should broaden the context. Can you extend your code sample and make it less abstract please.

Comment: did you try something like:
`await page.$$eval('li', (list, value) => list.find(e => e.innerText === value), val)`

Answer (score 28):

You are attempting to return DOM elements from [`page.$$eval()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args), which will return [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) because DOM elements are not [serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description).

Try using [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) instead if you would like to return an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) array.

Take a look at the [Puppeteer Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) for `page.$$eval()` below:

> #### page.$$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])
>
> - `selector` <[string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)> A [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to query page for
> - `pageFunction` <[function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)> Function to be evaluated in browser context
> - `...args` <...[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)|[JSHandle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-jshandle)> Arguments to pass to `pageFunction`
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)<[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)>> Promise which resolves to the return value of `pageFunction`
>
> This method runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page and passes it as the first argument to `pageFunction`.
>
> If `pageFunction` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), then `page.$$eval` would wait for the promise to resolve and return its value.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> const divsCounts = await page.$$eval('div', divs => divs.length);
> ```

Answer (score 11):

Just try to map your array to more serializable one.

For example:

```
const links = await page.$$eval('h1 > a', e=>e.map((a)=>a.href))
```