# How can I get elements in block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I can't to get inner block

On the page I got list of div.className .
But how can I get value of `$('.className').children('.subClassName')`?

```
const rows = await page.$$eval('.market_listing_row', items => items)
const prices = await rows.$$eval('.market_table_value.market_table_value > .normal_price', items => items.map(item => item.textContent))
```

I want to get each `subObject`, but I can't do it by variable rows.

Tried

```
const rows = await page.$$('.market_listing_row', items => items)
const prices = await rows.$$eval('.market_table_value.market_table_value > .normal_price', items => items.map(item => item.textContent))
```

But got error

> TypeError: rows.$$eval is not a function

Comment: It would help if you create a [mcve] of your code not working - why doesn't `$('.className').children('.subClassName')` work?  It is not very clear what your problem is

Comment: Possible dupe. This answer says use `page.$$` instead of `page.$$eval`. Also if you are just trying to scrape a page, I suggest you use cheerio or mozilla's readability library. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280984/how-to-use-eval-function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use .$$eval function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280984/how-to-use-eval-function)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question in my opinion. This is more about how to correctly use the `page.$` together with the `elementHandle.$$eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities for that.

**Option 1: Just use one selector**

If you want the selector for `.class2` inside `.class1`, this is simply: `.class1 .class2`. So you could just write the following code:

```js
const prices = await page.$$eval('.market_listing_row .market_table_value.market_table_value > .normal_price', items => items.map(item => item.textContent))
```

**Option 2: Use a puppeteer query on the element handle**

If you need to element handle for some other reason, you can also do a query on another query. Your second code sample was already close, but you used the `page.$$` function which results in array with element handels. Therefore you get the error.

```js
const rows = await page.$$('.market_listing_row');
for (const row of rows) {
    const value = await row.$$eval('.market_table_value.market_table_value > .normal_price', items => items.map(item => item.textContent))
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: I got 1 block by this way. But on page from 1 to 10 items.

Comment: @AndreyKadnikov Can you give a link to the page? Otherwise this will be hard to debug ;)

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?
I need parse item name and price

Comment: @AndreyKadnikov Had a typo in option 1. Option 1 works for me and should give you a list of 10 items.

Comment: Yes, And for naming I can use that. But more comfort to get a list of blocks and working with each of that. Can I do it?

Comment: @AndreyKadnikov Changed the second code sample to fit more to what you want. You might want to upvote/[accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it helped you :)

Answer (score -2):

In native javascript, you might use `.childNodes` to access the direct children nodes of a specific element. This will be an array of nodes.

FYI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

In order to get element value, you can use `.innerText` to extract the value.

FYI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Comment: not so sure why you down-voted this but this is the proper approach of using native javavscript, and it works.

Comment: He's using puppeteer. This is not a solution to the original problem.