# page.evaluate() with document.querySelectorAll() returns undefined or empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I am trying to scrape the web responses from this site https://chat.kuki.ai/ using Puppeteer. I have tried using `page.$eval` and `page.$$eval`. I've also tried this, https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/17934751.html
and,
[Puppeteer page.evaluate querySelectorAll return empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377955/puppeteer-page-evaluate-queryselectorall-return-empty-objects)
and,
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/489.
Each time, I get either an `undefined` object or and empty array.
My current code is:

```
const botResponses = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
        let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
        let responses = elements.map(element => {
            return element.innerText;
        })
        return responses;
    }, ".pb-chat-bubble pb-chat-bubble__bot");
```

The code returns an empty list. The selector in the code is a valid selector and you can check on the website to confirm. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show your a runnable [mcve]. Are you awaiting the selector to be available on a previous line before calling `page.evaluate`? As an aside, [`page.$$eval` is a shorthand for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51471105/6243352).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [page.$$eval](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args)

```js
const botResponses = await page.$$eval(".pb-chat-bubble pb-chat-bubble__bot",el=>el.innerText)
```

It does the same thing you're doing above with less code