# Getting element handle while scraping google maps reviews by puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am working on a scraping project in which I am scraping google maps reviews by using puppeteer JS. My all tags are working correctly, but when I try to parse "user review" it returns me an element handle object.

Here is my code:

```
await page.goto(url,{ waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });

await page.waitForSelector('.m6QErb', { visible: true })

title = title.concat(
  await page.$$eval(".d4r55", (els) =>
    els.map((e) => e.innerText)
  )
);

rating = rating.concat(
  await page.$$eval('.kvMYJc' , (els) => 
  els.map((e) => e.getAttribute('aria-label'))
))

reviews = reviews.concat(
  await page.$$eval(".MyEned span.wiI7pd" , (els) => 
  {
  els.map((e) => e.innerText)
  }
)) //this is returning me an element handle object
```

And this is the URL I am using:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Eiffel+Tower/@48.8583701,2.2901039,16z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d:0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!8m2!3d48.8583701!4d2.2944813!9m1!1b1
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code. It should be `$$eval`, not `$$`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280984/how-to-use-eval-function. I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already it returned me an empty array, but thanks for correcting the typo.

Comment: So I tried using ".MyEned" as the only selector class, and it returned me the required results.

Comment: Your original selector should work. Have you tried printing out the HTML (in your JS code) that you're querying against?

Comment: As an aside, you may want to start using the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). The keywords you should look for (Ctrl+F) are: `name`, `rating`, and `reviews`. The content generated that's rendered on Google Maps is not meant to be read by a machine.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried that original selector, it is working now, I think I just wrote it wrong before. Again thanks for correcting me sir!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the information from the Google Maps reviews page using the code below (also [check it in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-Maps-Reviews-answer#index.js)):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const placeUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Eiffel+Tower/@48.8583701,2.2901039,16z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47e66e2964e34e2d:0x8ddca9ee380ef7e0!8m2!3d48.8583701!4d2.2944813'

async function scrollPage(page, scrollContainer) {
  let lastHeight = await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("${scrollContainer}").scrollHeight`);
  while (true) {
    await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("${scrollContainer}").scrollTo(0, document.querySelector("${scrollContainer}").scrollHeight)`);
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
    let newHeight = await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("${scrollContainer}").scrollHeight`);
    if (newHeight === lastHeight) {
      break;
    }
    lastHeight = newHeight;
  }
}

async function getReviewsFromPage(page) {
  const reviews = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".jftiEf")).map((el) => {
      return {
        user: {
          name: el.querySelector(".d4r55")?.textContent.trim(),
          link: el.querySelector(".WNxzHc a")?.getAttribute("href"),
          thumbnail: el.querySelector(".NBa7we")?.getAttribute("src"),
          localGuide: el.querySelector(".RfnDt span:first-child").style.display === "none" ? undefined : true,
          reviews: parseInt(el.querySelector(".RfnDt span:last-child")?.textContent.replace("·", "")),
        },
        rating: parseFloat(el.querySelector(".kvMYJc")?.getAttribute("aria-label")),
        date: el.querySelector(".rsqaWe")?.textContent.trim(),
        snippet: el.querySelector(".MyEned")?.textContent.trim(),
        likes: parseFloat(el.querySelector(".GBkF3d:nth-child(2)")?.getAttribute("aria-label")),
        images: Array.from(el.querySelectorAll(".KtCyie button")).length
          ? Array.from(el.querySelectorAll(".KtCyie button")).map((el) => {
              return {
                thumbnail: getComputedStyle(el).backgroundImage.slice(5, -2),
              };
            })
          : undefined,
        date: el.querySelector(".rsqaWe")?.textContent.trim(),
      };
    });
  });
  return reviews;
}

async function fillPlaceInfo(page) {
  const placeInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return {
      title: document.querySelector(".DUwDvf").textContent.trim(),
      address: document.querySelector("button[data-item-id='address']")?.textContent.trim(), // data-item-id attribute may be different if the language is not English
      rating: document.querySelector("div.F7nice").textContent.trim(),
      reviews: document.querySelector("span.F7nice").textContent.trim().split(" ")[0],
    };
  });
  return placeInfo;
}

async function getLocalPlaceReviews() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);
  await page.goto(placeUrl);
  await page.waitForSelector(".DUwDvf");

  const placeInfo = await fillPlaceInfo(page);

  await page.click(".mgr77e .DkEaL");
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
  await page.waitForSelector(".jftiEf");

  // await scrollPage(page, '.DxyBCb');

  const reviews = await getReviewsFromPage(page);

  await browser.close();

  return { placeInfo, reviews };
}

getLocalPlaceReviews().then(console.log);
```

If you want to get all reviews (not only from the first page), you need to uncomment line

```js
await scrollPage(page, '.DxyBCb');
```

Output:

```json
{
   "placeInfo":{
      "title":"Eiffel Tower",
      "address":"Champ de Mars, 5 Av. Anatole France, 75007 Paris, France",
      "rating":"4.7",
      "reviews":"296,235"
   },
   "reviews":[
      {
         "user":{
            "name":"Chris Petrik",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/105283592710083789031/reviews?hl=en-US",
            "thumbnail":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AFdZucoZXWYCGWuPQpSzxrEQ6_QAs1FfuUYCGsH8e4tj8KM=w36-h36-p-c0x00000000-rp-mo-ba5-br100",
            "localGuide":true,
            "reviews":48
         },
         "rating":5,
         "date":"5 months ago",
         "snippet":"I mean, come on...it's the Eiffel Tower! This is a magical place. The view of Paris from the top is absolutely breathtaking. The day we went it was not too crowded, so it made things much easier. This was part of our Honeymoon and I am.so …",
         "likes":63,
         "images":[
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPgClEw3JwTLJOuf-DqC2xtZRodoavkpYVFBYqu=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            },
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOIbD6g6nNgBH6ojj_OyqIFnQEDs8mHJOejDEs0=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            },
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipM7jHcKnsTdnOc4ZDZ4O22BA7WKSldfLTbTcLq3=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            },
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPIeo83uGbdZLFFxfU0s6EQcUtHASohuUq5015U=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "user":{
            "name":"Rudro Rana",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/113301929922891906080/reviews?hl=en-US",
            "thumbnail":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AFdZucoz9H1zqYCq4Z8nj1tBkzwFOCQaQepigI6vvaOrFQ=w36-h36-p-c0x00000000-rp-mo-ba4-br100",
            "localGuide":true,
            "reviews":86
         },
         "rating":5,
         "date":"6 months ago",
         "snippet":"The most spectacular and wonderful place in Paris. The Eiffel tower is historical place, but looks modern at the same time. The view from the top of the Eiffel is magnificent and breathtaking. The view of skyscraper and different historical …",
         "likes":24,
         "images":[
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOs9TSNoyYmW1GL4SH9PlkAihvWsUbMTn-8O2Sj=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            },
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMqIy_ik9TMotJPBn7uuIat-6ulc42OG95wN0WB=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            },
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipNZfqb-BSQ2gETyJd3ye4l2s7Cv7ttWkH9aOc00=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            },
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPrTQSSiUCMMDgVgvLPE9zSpCPj4E2YNp0IPIS3=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "user":{
            "name":"Laura",
            "link":"https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/103073735774223183506/reviews?hl=en-US",
            "thumbnail":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AItbvmk2xfd1DFgsFDiKkUJF8qTe_Alam2fJJoSor1sW=w36-h36-p-c0x00000000-rp-mo-ba4-br100",
            "localGuide":true,
            "reviews":44
         },
         "rating":4,
         "date":"3 months ago",
         "snippet":"We went with a tour company which allowed us to get through the queues faster- that was worth it. We also bought summit tickets. It was cool going up to the summit (a little nauseating) but in terms of enjoying the views the second floor …",
         "likes":12,
         "images":[
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipMBRGdJb3zL1rME20osajG-bosdIV8U82VTYS1n=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            },
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipN2t_lVvQzucqwV_kPE8YfrNANJVc73e3oT-c-p=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            },
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipOynJwoev37FdtckuYCrNeDHczSngytMITHsid7=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            },
            {
               "thumbnail":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPPxtgyiV9N85IpbeekCX2dweCAMB2_FI0_CfOx=w300-h225-p-k-no"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

You can read more about scraping Google Maps Reviews from my blog post [Web Scraping Google Maps Reviews with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-google-maps-reviews-with-nodejs/).